# How do i integrate vue-router and laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Currently i am using vue and laravel together.Vue for frontend and laravel for backend api.I am trying to use vue-router with laravel but couldnt make it work.
What i am trying to do is reach http://localhost/ec/public/#/login
app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import Router from './routes.js'


Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('login', require('./components/Login.vue'));
Vue.component('register', require('./components/Register.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router:Router
});
```

I have created a file in same dir app.js called routes.js:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Login from './components/Login.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
routes:[
{
path:"/login",
component:Login

}


]



})
export default router
```

welcome.blade.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title> site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="app">



       </div>







       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If i ad  to welcome.blade.php i get component not registered error

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `<router-view></router-view>` within your `welcome.blade.php`

#### Update

I could say that the order of the import, try to import Vue 1st then import vue-router. Otherwise you can't skip the `<router-view></router-view>` because it is an element of vue-router itself.

Comment: hi if i do that i get app.js:36580 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in <Root>)